# Good Website for aspiring Java technical architects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture

I was trying to find out a good website for aspiring technical architects. To be precise, I have worked for 10 years in Java/J2EE areas, and now would like to gain further knowledge on architecture side of application. At the same time If I could see upcoming trends in technology that could provide a roadmap for Java professionals, would be of great help.

I usually get an hour or two to spend on doing extra things that includes scanning web sites, reading some articles etc..

I would like to know from experts, what site usually can be referred that can enrich me with good knowledge by spending an hour or two regularly? Or If you can share your experience would certainly help.

Comment: What kind of information do you believe you *weren't* getting during the previous 10 years? How did you keep up with technology trends up until now?

Comment: Voting to migrate to Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Dave, I mainly work on web related projects and depending upon technology involved I usually go through them. However there are lot of innovations happening in other areas like Mobile, Cloud, different APIs getting release in Open source technology that usually I didn't get chance to work because my Project doesn't need them. Earlier I've been follower of Serverside, DZone etc..

Comment: But There are lot of other things happening on enterprize development front that an architect need to keep track of and I find them distributed across these web sites. I'm also planning to switch my role from a tech lead towards an architect that mainly focus on designing new systems or improving their designs (mainly in J2EE area).

Answer (score 3):

I like [infoq](http://www.infoq.com).

Answer (score 1):

I like Java Posse. They have lot of relevant podcasts for technical architects http://www.javaposse.com/

Answer (score 0):

[java lobby on dzone](http://java.dzone.com/) is quite a nice place, but you probably have already found that out. they do publish a variety of excellent quality articles.